# Drupal 8 contact form dont send Message in Email

Tags: forms, email, drupal-8, contact-form

I made a Drupal 8 website with a Contact form.
On submit, the form send an email to the specified address but without the Message field. The name, sender email and subject are sent.

I tested with the version 8.4.5 and 8.5.3, it doesn't work anywhere. In the mail it's written that the form was sent to "https://mywebsite.com/user/login" or "https://mywebsite.com/user/1" if the user is logger in, thats strange but I don't know how to change it.
The content of the mail is :

```
Sender Name (not checked) (sadfasdf @ sdfsdf) used the contact form at https://mywebsite.com/user/login to send a message.
```

I may have something to do with the id of the input element. But I don't know how to change it.

Does somebody had the same problem? Can anyone help me?

Best Regards, 
Adrian Buntschu

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Scratch that. I was experiencing the same issue. Fixed by upgrading to 8.6.0